# Keycloak with user verification using SMS

Tags: java, microservices, keycloak, keycloak-connect

After looking at keycloak I could not find a way to do any SMS verification.

Do you guys have any extension or setup in order to allow user verification with SMS.

Thanks for your help.

Jonathan.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the sample code from official github, now the keycloak version is 11+

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/action-token-authenticator

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/providers/authenticator

Answer (score 2):

The best example I found was this one. He has a blog post and a 20 minute video to explain it. It was done December of 2020 and it built and ran right out of the box.

https://www.n-k.de/2020/12/keycloak-2fa-sms-authentication.html

code for the above blog post:
https://github.com/dasniko/keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator

there's even a video
https://youtu.be/GQi19817fFk

Answer (score 0):

I believe this needs to be a [custom authentication SPI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_auth_spi) in Keycloak.

There are a couple of nice examples that seem to solve your problem. In case [keycloak-sms-authenticator](https://github.com/gwallet/keycloak-sms-authenticator) doesn't solve your purpose, then you can take a look at the source code and tweak it according to your need.

Comment: the code is too old to run, the version is 2.2.1, now it's 11.0+

Comment: I am using keycloak 12.0. Was someone able to use this code with version 12?